# Pandas - how to get count of negative and positive values in a row

Tags: python, pandas

How can I count the number (count) and sum of negative and positive values in a row without many loops in pandas? I want to get the maximum sum of consecutive negatives and also the maximum sum of consecutive positives . Example dataframe:

```
datetime                 Value
2018-11-12 15:10:00       2.00
2018-11-12 15:20:00     -10.50
2018-11-12 15:30:00      10.50
2018-11-12 15:40:00       7.50
2018-11-12 15:50:00       8.00
2018-11-12 16:10:00     -20.00
2018-11-12 16:20:00     -10.00
```

I would like the output to be:

```
Max # of negatives in a row: 2, Total value = -30.00
Max # of positives in a row: 3, Total value =  26.00
```

A simple `pd.groupby()` doesn't solve the issue since it doesn't group the order. Maybe some sort of sql query? `pd.query()`?

Comment: Can you please explain your expected output? Is it in accordance to the shared input?

Comment: row? or column? your sample output and sample data do not seem to be matching. i Presume you want the Value column to show positives and negatives, which would make #3 negatives for a value of -40, and #4 positives for a value of 27.

Comment: The output does match.. I want the number of negatives in a row, and to sum their total values. Since it's time series I want to see how many negatives happen in a row, and what that total sum comes out to be. I also want that for positives but if I figure out one the other should be easy.

Comment: Im afraid i dont follow. could you elaborate? for example, point me to values which add up to -30 that are being used together in your sample.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh looks like the 26 is 10.50 + 7.50 + 8.00 and the -30 is the last two rows of -20.00 and -10.00 - not sure what happened to the first two rows or what happens otherwise regarding negative/positives though... Matt - can you elaborate with expected output and maybe rephrase your criteria - it's a little ambiguous?

Comment: This answer should be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296945/how-to-count-all-positive-and-negative-values-in-a-pandas-groupby

Comment: I rephrased it slightly. Maybe it's just me.. i don't think the question is ambiguous. I am pretty clear by saying "the number of negative and positive values in a row."

Comment: @Matt so the longest contiguous of positive/negative runs in the value column then? If you only had the first two rows in your example, it'd be those two rows with a count of 1? What happens if there's equally sized groups?

Comment: For equally sized groups it doesn't matter since the function I am looking for will return two outputs: max and min, each with a count and a sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to firstly give every "same sign in a row"-group a different number in order to proceed with `groupby`.
Comparing Value with its shifted array with regards to sign gives the separators of those groups. Cumulative summation then leads to unique numbers, identifiers if you want:

```
df['grpnum'] = (np.sign(df.Value) != np.sign(df.Value.shift())).cumsum()
```

Then you can groupby this identifier and calculate the groups length, sum and their sign:

```
ranking = df.groupby('grpnum').agg([sum, len, lambda x: sum(x)>0]).Value
```

which leads to

```
         sum  len  <lambda>
grpnum                     
1        2.0  1.0      True
2      -10.5  1.0     False
3       26.0  3.0      True
4      -30.0  2.0     False

print(ranking.groupby('<lambda>')['sum', 'len'].apply(lambda g: g[g['len']==g['len'].max()]))

                  sum  len
<lambda> grpnum           
True     3       26.0  3.0
False    4      -30.0  2.0
```

Comment: Coming back to this a few years later. Just a follow up to speed up performance: ```ranking = df.groupby('grpnum')['Value'].agg([sum, len, lambda x: sum(x)>0])``` is much faster since it's not passing the entire df to the groupby